# storing data as object not array in php / laravel

Tags: php, oop, laravel, object

I'm pulling data out of a blade template using:

```
@foreach ($links as $link)
    <p>{{ ($link['title']) }} </p>
@endforeach
```

I'd like to use:

```
@foreach ($links as $link)
    <p>{{ ($link->title) }} </p>
@endforeach
```

But I'm not storing my data as an object in the controller. **How do I store data as an object?**

My controller code:

```
foreach($json['items'] as $item) {


    $link = [

        'vidId' => $item['id']['videoId'],
        'title' => $item['snippet']['title'],
        'thumb' => $item['snippet']['thumbnails']['high']['url']
    ];

    $links[] = $link;

}

$data['links'] = $links;
$data['v'] = $v;

return view('results', $data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast the array to object:

```
$obj_links = (object)$links;
```

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote the controller like so:

```
foreach($json['items'] as $item) {

    $link = new \stdClass;
    $link -> vidId = $item['id']['videoId'];
    $link -> title = $item['snippet']['title'];
    $link -> thumb = $item['snippet']['thumbnails']['high']['url'];

    $links[] = $link;

}

$data = [
    'links' => $links,
    'v' => $v
];


return view('results')->with($data);
```